# Environment variable not expanded inside the command line argument

Tags: bash, shell, awk, quoting, variable-substitution

I have a file `user-pid.out2` which has "usernumber" and "process id" as two columns. based on usernumber I want to find corresponding process id. the first two lines below does not show the output correct but when I hardcode the user as 62 in line 3 & 4 it shows the process id corresponding to user 62. Could someone help please.

```
USR=62
usrpid=`awk '$1 == "$USR" {print $2}' /home/hu/batchhu/dbscripts_tst2/user-pid.out2`
echo "first:" $USR $usrpid
# This shows 62 and blank for process id

usrpid=`awk '$1 == "62" {print $2}' /home/hu/batchhu/dbscripts_tst2/user-pid.out2`
echo  "second:" $USR $usrpid
# This shows 62 and process id corresponding to this user in the file user-pid.out2
```

Answer (score 9):

@artm showed a technique where you double-quote the awk script and escape various characters. Here are 3 other techniques

Break out of the single quote to let the shell expand the variable

```
usrpid=$(awk '$1 == "'"$USR"'" {print $2}' file)
```

Pass the shell variable into an awk variable

```
usrpid=$(awk -v usr="$USR" '$1 == usr {print $2}' file)
```

If the variable is exported, use awk's ENVIRON array

```
usrpid=$(awk '$1 == ENVIRON["USR"] {print $2}' file)
```

That latter one should be the preferred one.

In the first approach like for @artm's one, the content of the shell variable is embedded inside the `awk` code, so that becomes a *command injection vulnerability* if the content of the variable is not tightly controlled (for instance, with `USR='blah" || system("reboot") || "'`, that would call `reboot`).

The second one does not introduce a command injection vulnerability but if `$USR` contains backslash characters, the `usr` `awk` variable will not contain the same thing as the `$USR` shell variable as `awk` expands C-like backslash escape sequences in there.

Using `ENVIRON` has none of those issues.

Answer (score 3):

the `"$USR"` in the first example isn't expanded because it occurs inside the single-quoted string `'$1 == "$USR" { print $2 }'`, so this code is looking for a row with the first column being "$USR", not 62.

The following should work:

```
usrpid=$(awk "\$1 == \"$USR\" {print \$2}" /home/hu/batchhu/dbscripts_tst2/user-pid.out2)
```

Changes:

1. the awk command line uses double quotes so $USR is expanded
2. dollar signs and quote characters inside the awk program are escaped
3. `$()` is used instead of backticks so [the backslashes are handled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/538534)

Do note that since the value of `USR` is interpolated directly into the awk script, it only works if that value only contains characters that awk will interpret literally: if `$USR` contains `\` or `"`, all hell will break loose — `"` would be the end of the awk string literal, and `\` would quote the next character.