# invalid char '@' in expression awk output

Tags: text-processing, awk, ksh

I have an awk command on **ksh** script, the command extract fields from a log file to then struct them in new one.

```
ultimate=$(grep -oP 'Time:\K.*' $log2 | column -t | awk '{print $3,"/","'"$month"'","/",$2,";",$4,";","'"$fBrand"'",";",'"$fUser"'",";","'"$fSerial"'",";","'"$fEmail"'",";","'"$fLocation"'",";"}' | sort | sed 's: ::g')
```

when I execute the script, it returns to me:

```
awk: cmd. line:934: 22",";","email@bla.bla.com",";","fn,",";"
awk: cmd. line:934:               ^ invalid char '@' in expression
```

Comment: Mother of quotes...Not really a duplicate but this should help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120788/237982

Comment: haha I'll find another way to improve the order. Thanks

Comment: This answer covers some better alternatives to passing variables into awk: [Environment variable not expanded inside the command line argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162699/65304)